# Valid futures vs Default constructed futures

Tags: c++, validation, future, concurrent.futures, futuretask

I am studying futures in my concurrent programming class. My professor has stated this in her slides:

```
"Valid" futures are future objects associated to a 
shared state, and are constructed by calling one of the following functions:

async
promise::get_future
packaged_task::get_future
```

> future objects are only useful when they
>   are valid. Default-constructed future objects are
>   not valid (unless move-assigned a valid future).

I can't understand the meaning of the above, especially the "unless move-assigned a valid future" part. Could someone please explain this in simple terms, and perhaps show some example code as well?

Comment: An oddity of `std::future` is that [*none* of its constructors or methods can make a future object valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020793/what-gives-a-stdfuture-some-shared-state).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [`std::future` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/future):

> Default-constructed future objects are not valid

This just means calling the default constructor for the object, something like:

```
std::future<int> f;
```

This will call constructor #1 which states:

> Default constructor. Constructs a std::future with no shared state.
>   **After construction, `valid() == false`.**

As for the other part:

> (unless move-assigned a valid future)

What is meant here is that the move constructor (`future( future&& other )` #2) will be called which states:

> Move constructor. Constructs a std::future with the shared state of
>   other using move semantics. After construction, `other.valid() == false`.

Basically, the state of `other` in this constructor is *moved* to `this`. That means if `other.valid() == true` then after the move constructor has returned `other.valid()` will be `false` and `this.valid()` will be `true`. If `other.valid()` was `false` to begin with then both will end up `false`.

```
std::future<int> fut; // fut.valid() == false, default constructor

std::future<int> valid_fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ return 42; }); // obtain a valid std::future..
// valid_fut.valid() == true here

//now move valid_fut into new_fut
std::future<int> new_fut(std::move(valid_fut));
// new_fut.valid() == true
// valid_fut.valid() == false
```

To summarize:

- Calling the default constructor for an `std::future` will result in `valid() == false`. Always.
- Calling the move constructor for an `std::future` will result in `valid() == true` *only* if `other.valid()` was `true` before moving from it. False otherwise.

Comment: Small nitpick: the move constructor does not neccesarily come into play. What they literally mean is that if, at the end of your example, you were to do ```fut = std::move(new_fut);```, fut will be valid. That's the move-assignment they're talking about. (You actually also show this when assigning to valid_fut, though the compiler will try to treat that as a move constructor, not move assignment.)