# What gives a std::future some shared state

Tags: c++, future

A [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) has a [`std::future::valid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid) method, which indicates whether the future object refers to some *shared state*. None of the constructors construct a future object that refers to *shared state* (except the move constructor, which can move the *shared state* from one future object to another). **All** the methods of the class ([`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get), [`wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait), [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) and [`wait_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until) require the future object to have shared state as a precondition (they have undefined behaviour if `valid() == false`). How then can a `std::future` acquire some *shared state* and become useful?

Comment: I am answering my own question, [as is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: More power to you, especially since you posted the two in tandem (some users don't, and it's confusing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not normally use a `std::future` in isolation; you use it with a [`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise). The `std::promise` [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise) set up some *shared state*. You can then use the [`std::promise::get_future()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/get_future) method to get a `std::future` that refers to that *shared state*.

Comment: Perhaps an example would be useful?

Comment: [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and [`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) also create futures